# Curl shell script not giving variables to php file

Tags: php, mysql, shell, curl

**What I want**

With an Apple Script I'm getting some information from my local machine. Now I want these information to be written into a MySQL Database.

**My Code**

Right now I'm getting all my Information and writing them into variables. Then I'm creating a URL to transfer these information to my PHP Script which handles the writing into the database. In this created URL string I'm replacing all spaces with **"%20"** (because of URL friendliness).

Now I'm running a shell script with curl navigating to the specified URL.

```
set aString to "http://localhost/clientinfo/setlogin.php?a=" & info_hostname & "&b=" & info_modelname & "&c=" & info_macaddress & "&d=" & info_osversion & "&e=" & info_cpuname & "&f=" & info_cpuspeed & "&g=" & info_ram & "&h=" & info_serial

set my text item delimiters to " "
set split_list to every text item of aString
set my text item delimiters to "%20"
set newString to (split_list as text)

do shell script "curl " & newString
```

The URL generated looks like this after all the coding:

> http://localhost/clientinfo/setlogin.php?a=hostname&b=Mac%20mini&c=0c:4d:e9:ee:d5:58&d=10.9&e=Intel%20Core%20i5&f=2.5%20GHz&g=8%20GB&h=C07MW1XMH

**The Problem**

The PHP Script tells me, that every other `"$_GET"` variable after the first one is not specified.

Snippet of curl output:

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: b in <b>setlogin.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
```

When I output my generated URL and type it into the address bar in my browser it works.

What is wrong with the curl script?

Comment: what happens if you use &amp; instead of & ?

Comment: still not working @PerroVerd

Comment: Add verbose/trace arguments to the curl command and see what it outputs about the request it is sending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line of your script is calling curl and the generated query, the problem seems that is running through a shell and & its a special character (put things on background) so probably you need to use quotes to avoid the string being interpreted

```
do shell script "curl \"" & newString & "\""
```

Comment: Perfect! That was the solution.. THANKS!!